# Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, migration, entity-framework-migrations

I, for the life of me, can't get rid of this error message. I have tried almost everything that I can.

MyDBContext.cs

```
        public MyDBContext() : base("ConnStr_Dev")
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDBContext, DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyDBContext>>());
        //Database.SetInitializer<MyDBContext>(null);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

GenericRepository.cs

```
        public void Insert(T obj)
    {
        table.Add(obj);      //this is where it throws the error, inserting first time.
    }
```

Tried all of these in different combinations

Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations -Force

Add-migration Initial -IgnoreChanges

Update-Database

I have tried deleting the Migrations table, deleting the entire database, everything.

Any Migrations experts please?

Edit: the DAL contains the GenericRepository and the context class.

Comment: This line of code: `Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDBContext, DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyDBContext>>());` shouldn't be there. If you comment this is working?

Comment: A better way to ensure that your database is up-to-date is to move `Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDBContext, DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyDBContext>>());` to `Application_Start()` method.

Comment: Move your initializer to the static constructor. Make sure the project with the context is selected in the console (or use command parameters to point there). Are you using Identity (which has it's own context) ?

Answer (score 3):

I fought with this error too. I added the migration and then made what I thought was a trivial change.

This property: `IMigrationMetadata.Target` in your migration isn't random. It's computed based on the state of the model at the time the migration was completed. (That may be an oversimplification.)

So if you make additional changes, it looks as there are additional pending changes that require yet another migration.

In my case, because the changes hadn't been committed to source control, the fix was to delete and re-add the migration. It took a while to figure out the cause because the error message is unclear unless you already know what's causing it. But the lesson I learned (being relatively new to EF) is that changes to the models require either a new migration or re-doing the migration that I'm working on.

Answer (score 2):

1. Delete your `Migrations` folder from your solution
2. Delete the `dbo.__MigrationHistory` table from your database
3. Open `Package Manager Console` and `Enable-Migrations`
4. Add your initial migration `Add-Migration Initial`
5. `Update-Database`
6. Done

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I already tried this, there's something else I am doing wrong. Just to be sure, I have to run Migrations on the DAL project, right?

Comment: did you check your connectionstring appsetting is right and uncommented, in my case, its resolved..weirdo!

Answer (score 2):

You simply made changes to one or more of your entity classes. Whether you added a new property, changed the data type of that particular property or you simply added a new entity class, in all of those cases you indeed need to add a new migration.

Seeing that you've already tried that, make sure that when you execute the Add-Migration command in Package Manager Console that you've **selected the project that contains your DBContext class**, the **Configuration** class and **Migrations** folder. Furthermore, you are passing a specific connection string to the base class (DbContext) of the *MyDBContext* class. Make sure you are also upgrading and updating the correct database.

Know that you can perform an Add-Migration command and an Update command to a specific database:

Example snippets:

```
Add-Migration AddProperty1 -ConnectionString "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseCatablog;Connect Timeout=30;User ID=MyUser;Password=mypassword12345" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient" -Verbose
```

and

```
Update-Database -ConnectionString "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseCatablog;Connect Timeout=30;User ID=MyUser;Password=mypassword12345" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient" -Verbose
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was resolved by adding a DatabaseInitializerForType... appSetting.

```
<appSettings>
<add key="DatabaseInitializerForType EasyEntity.EasyContext, EasyEntity"  value="EasyEntity.EasyInitializer, EasyEntity" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is weird enough in my case, I forgot to uncomment the CONNECTIONSTRING setting, means having a proper connectionstring resolved this error. Hope it helps!